# TabLayout's tabIndicator custom width can be changed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-tablayout

Let's say I got something like this:

[image: current width of tabIndicator]

but I want something like this:

[image: target width of tabIndicator]

Is there a chance to do it cause I cannot find anything about `tabIndicator`'s width...

Comment: have a look at the `TabLayout`'s default style.

Answer (score 0):

I have founded a library that could help you: 
https://github.com/H07000223/FlycoTabLayout